# What kind of guitar exercise is "the caterpillar"?

Tags: guitar, practice, exercises

What does it consist in and how do you practice it?

Answer (score 11):

```
$6 5 6 7 8 $5 5 6 7 8 $4 5 6 7 8 $3 5 6 7 8 $2 5 6 7 8 $1 5 6 7 8
```

See: [this link](http://www.zanesguitartuition.com.au/Assets/pdf/the_%20catapillar.pdf) for detailed instructions.  It's walking up the strings of the guitar while keeping your fingers in position.

Comment: Ok! I actually knew this exercise, but I didn't know it was called like this ;)

Comment: @reg Check also the intro tab of the song *Erotomania* by Dream Theater for a *crippled* caterpillar.